# android 2.2 popup not displaying text in multiline

Tags: android

I am displying a long text in textview on popup in android. It is properly working on higher version (4.1 and 4.2) of android. But in 2.2 it just display the text in single line and text is not displaying in more than one line.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/floating_background"
>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_image" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/lite_email_msg"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dialog_title"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_close"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_cancel"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/cancel"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Comment: i added the xml file. i am loading this xml as a popup in click of a button.

Comment: I found the solution. need to add android:scrollHorizontally="false" and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add android:scrollHorizontally="false" in textview and it will work. enjoy:)